# Generate date range from start date and end date SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, azure-sql-database, recursive-query

I need to generate a date range that comes from a table like this:

```
id | start_date  | end_date
---+-------------+------------
1  | 2020-01-01  | 2020-01-03
2  | 2020-01-01  | 2020-01-03
```

The result would have to be this:

```
id | date
---+------------
1  | 2020-01-01
1  | 2020-01-02
1  | 2020-01-03
2  | 2020-01-01
2  | 2020-01-02
2  | 2020-01-03
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a good spot to use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select id, start_date as date, end_date from mytable
    union all
    select id, dateadd(day, 1, date), end_date from cte where date < end_date
)
select date from cte
```

If your intervals may span over more than 100 days, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.